# Magento 2 : How to Override Core Template Magento_Review::helper/summary.phtml

Tags: phtml, review, variables, product-review

How to change the template in a custom module.

Original path = vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary.phtml

I want to change this template to my own when my module is enabled ONLY

I have looked at a few tests that I could gather from Online and nothing worked.

the way Magento show this summary.phtml is by this way

```
protected $_availableTemplates = [
    self::FULL_VIEW => 'Magento_Review::helper/summary.phtml',
    self::SHORT_VIEW => 'Magento_Review::helper/summary_short.phtml',
];
```

Can anyone give me some guide or tips to change this template in a custom module.

The core file is coming from magento/module-review/Block/Product/ReviewRenderer.php

```
/**
 * Get review summary html
 *
 * @param Product $product
 * @param string $templateType
 * @param bool $displayIfNoReviews
 *
 * @return string
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function getReviewsSummaryHtml(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    $templateType = self::DEFAULT_VIEW,
    $displayIfNoReviews = false
) {
    if ($product->getRatingSummary() === null) {
        $this->reviewSummaryFactory->create()->appendSummaryDataToObject(
            $product,
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        );
    }

    if (null === $product->getRatingSummary() && !$displayIfNoReviews) {
        return '';
    }
    // pick template among available
    if (empty($this->_availableTemplates[$templateType])) {
        $templateType = self::DEFAULT_VIEW;
    }
    $this->setTemplate($this->_availableTemplates[$templateType]);

    $this->setDisplayIfEmpty($displayIfNoReviews);

    $this->setProduct($product);

    return $this->toHtml();
}
```

Comment: where the above template code return?

Comment: Try to customize usage of `$_availableTemplates` variable in your module via plugin(s).

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i have added the core file path

Comment: @Slava i won't be able to do a plugin on protected and it's not a function it's a varible

Comment: I mean that there is a point somewhere when `$_availableTemplates` variable is used, some method gets its value. So in that place you can try to use after plugin

Comment: @Slava i have updated the question section, in this function the core is calling setTemplate function that's where the variable is getting called

Comment: But i am not able to do a plugin, i couldn't find away

Comment: You can try to override ReviewRenderer class via preferences in your module and override `$_availableTemplates` variable in new class. All other methods will be used from parent, so not a big problem for upgradability.

Comment: I did try preference first, but i wasn't able to change it. i could be doing something wrong but i wasn't able to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the plugin of this function.

> public function getReviewsSummaryHtml

Where above variable is use to return the template.

Comment: how can i get a plugin for this function i have been trying beforePlugin and i am not able to do it

Comment: you need to create arround plugin.

Comment: is this is the correct way 
public function aroundGetReviewsSummaryHtml(\Magento\Review\Block\Product\ReviewRenderer $subject, callable $proceed)

or do i need to do 
public function aroundGetReviewsSummaryHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $templateType = self::DEFAULT_VIEW,
        $displayIfNoReviews = false,
\Magento\Review\Block\Product\ReviewRenderer $subject, callable $proceed)

Comment: if you have new question please ask it separately so other community member can also help you into that one.

Comment: If above answer help you into current asking question, please upvote and accept as solutions so it will help other in community. 
For how to create plugin, you can check this one : https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html